# How do I end a Tkinter python module on mac so I don't have to force quit python launcher after the program is done?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

app = Tk()

app.title('example')

app.geometry('400x300+200+200')

b = Button(app, text = "quit", command = app.quit)

b.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

When I run this python launcher pops up and when I close the window or press the quit button the window closes and the python idle says its done but python launcher becomes unresponsive and I have to force quit it for python launcher to quit and disappear from the dock.

Is there a command that I have to use to exit the code properly?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `sys.exit()`

Here is an example that works

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
class YourApp(Tk):
    def quit_and_close(self):
            app.quit()
            sys.exit()


app = YourApp()

app.title('example')

app.geometry('400x300+200+200')

b = Button(app, text = "quit", command = app.quit_and_close)

b.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This just causes spyder to freeze? The button can be pressed and the process ends in console, but the window remains open and a spinning beach ball pops up.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking all over and it seems like this might have been a known bug.

The best response I've gotten is from:

```
 window = tk.Tk()
 window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", window.destroy)
```

Which allows you to close the window with the little x. This ends the process in the spyder console window, but not the process in the applications bar on the mac. That must still be force quit.

I tried making a function like this to destroy the window and exit using sys, but this just causes the freeze again.

```
def CloseProgram():
    sys.exit()
    window.destroy()
```

Comment: Try using Terminal on Mac. I found that IDEs are a bit picky (I use IDLE), and Terminal does the job really well in ending the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Terminal instead of an IDE. I've found that IDEs are very finicky, and using Terminal properly exits and quits the Python Launcher.