# How to close or destroy Tkinter window on Mac

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, window

How can I destroy Tkinter window on Mac?

My code works fine with window and I could easily exit by clicking on X but on Mac, because of `mainloop()` and there's no X, I can't close.

So I tried to create shortcut or hotkey to easily close the window. (or tell me if there's other way around)

```
import tkinter

window=tkinter.Tk()

window.title("tkinter")
window.geometry("640x400+100+100")
window.resizable(False, False)

window.mainloop()
```

This is my Code. I could easily close on Window but not on Mac.

Maybe if I insert

```
def close_window(self):
    window.destroy()
window.bind('<Control-q>',close_window)
```

I could simply close by pressing Ctrl+Q but idk why this also returns error.

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Please, could you tell us which error it returns?

Comment: Not the python error. I get the same exact error as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601107/python-tkinter-window-not-closing

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456092/how-do-i-end-a-tkinter-python-module-on-mac-so-i-dont-have-to-force-quit-python

Comment: @LeoLeontev Thank you but I was trying to figure out if theres other way around rather than creating button.

Comment: I don't own a Mac, but I think you could process window close event by yourself (since window.destroy() does not work), like root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: sys.exit())

Comment: I'm also having this same issue.